# I need to use custom segues between nibs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my project i need to use a custom segue it is already created i just need to know how to implement it between nib/xib files. I use a button to move between the nib/xib if it matters.

Comment: Please you can add a context to your question?. The segue is between `UIViewControllers`, these can be represented by a xib, all this logic may be in code. Then there are many scenarios for this question, you could add more information by specifying your case?

Answer (score 0):

Segues can be used only in storyboard. If you have you UI in nibs, you need to instantiate it programmatically and present it like:

```
let controller = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController.pushViewController(self, animated: true)
```